# Unable to install assimp in Fedora

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, assimp

I am having trouble installing assimp in Fedora 30, I installed it using dnf

```
sudo dnf install assimp assimp-devel
```

Since my project uses qt5, I then did the following commands

```
qmake
make
```

but I received the following errors

```
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::Importer()'
undefined reference to `Assimp::Importer::~Importer()'
```

I searched in the internet and found that I had to link my project, thus I added the flag -lassimp to the Makefile, but then I got a new error.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/../../../../lib64/libassimp.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/9/../../../../lib64/libassimp.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream()@GLIBCXX_3.4.26'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code I want to execute in my project is the following:

```
Assimp::Importer importer;
```

and this is my .pro

```
TEMPLATE    = app
QT         += opengl


FORMS += MainForm.ui
LIBS += -lGLEW -lassimp
HEADERS += GraphicsWidget.hpp MainWidget.hpp Model/Model.hpp
CONFIG += warn_off
SOURCES += main.cpp MainWidget.cpp GraphicsWidget.cpp Model/Model.cpp
```

Now I am really lost, hope someone can help me
Thanks

Comment: show your .pro...

Comment: Okay, I just updated it  @eyllanesc

Comment: Are you using the x86 or the x64-build of Asset-Importer-Lib?

Comment: I listed my installed package and it figures as "assimp.x86_64" version :3.3.1-19.fc30. @KimKulling